# Breaking apart Javascript array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, flot

I have a array that has been built from reading in a csv file using [jquery.csv.js](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/) like so:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type : "GET",
    url : "data.csv",
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(csv) 
    {
        myData = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
            console.log(myData[i]);
    }
});
```

And a sample of the output looks like:
 `["-112.5", "15", "0", "0"]
["-112.5", "10", "0", "0"]
["-112.5", "5", "112.1667", "85.3819"]`

I am trying to plot this data using [FLOT](http://www.flotcharts.org/), so I need these values broken out into x,y coordinates like [-112.5, 15], [0, 0], [-112.5, 10], [0, 0], [-112.5, 5], [112.1667, 85.3819]

I have tried using nested for loops like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        newArray[i][j] = origArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

But this throws an Undefined error and looking around stack overflow, it is apparent JS doesn't handle arrays in the manner I am used to.

Would someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @ultranaut - Sorry, I was trying to be brief and instead made things more complicated. I updated the variables to better reflect what I was trying to do. myData is the array result from parsing the .csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you can't set `newArray[i][j]` before defining `newArray[i]`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++){
  newArray[i] = []; // <---

  for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    newArray[i][j] = origArray[i][j];
  }
}
```

But, you can also worry a little less about indexes (at least those of `newArray`) by taking [slices of each `origArray[i]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [pushing them to `newArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
for (var i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++) {
    var innerArray = origArray[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j += 2) {
        newArray.push(innerArray.slice(j, j + 2));
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PxPzt/

---

Otherwise, you can get the indexes needed for the desired result with the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < origArray[i].length; j++){
        var k = i * 2 + Math.floor(j / 2);

        if (newArray[k] == null)
            newArray[k] = [];

        newArray[k][j % 2] = origArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3tGL/

Comment: Slices were definitely the way to go for me. Works perfectly. Thank you!